# firewalld throws an error when using nftables backend

Tags: python, yocto, firewalld

I'm adding firewalld 1.2.0 into my yocto distro.
However, whenever I try to start it with debug messages (after removing the ipv6 rules), I get:

```
2023-05-24 12:40:54 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.ipXtables.ip4tables'>: /usr/sbin/iptables-restore /run/firewalld/temp.5p25jbxq: 116
   1: *security
   2: -F
   3: -X
   4: -Z
   5: COMMIT
   6: *raw
   7: -F
   8: -X
   9: -Z
  10: COMMIT
  11: *mangle
  12: -F
  13: -X
  14: -Z
  15: COMMIT
  16: *nat
  17: -F
  18: -X
  19: -Z
  20: COMMIT
  21: *filter
  22: -F
  23: -X
  24: -Z
  25: COMMIT
2023-05-24 12:40:54 DEBUG3: <class 'firewall.core.nftables.nftables'>: calling python-nftables with JSON blob: {"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"table": {"family": "inet", "name": "firewalld"}}}]}
2023-05-24 12:40:54 DEBUG1: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firewall/core/fw_transaction.py", line 116, in execute
self.fw.rules(backend_name, rules[backend_name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firewall/core/fw.py", line 1016, in rules
backend.set_rules(_rules, self._log_denied)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firewall/core/nftables.py", line 360, in set_rules
raise ValueError("'%s' failed: %s\nJSON blob:\n%s" % ("python-nftables", error, json.dumps(json_blob)))
ValueError: 'python-nftables' failed:
JSON blob:
{"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"table": {"family": "inet", "name": "firewalld"}}}]}

2023-05-24 12:40:54 ERROR: 'python-nftables' failed:
JSON blob:
{"nftables": [{"metainfo": {"json_schema_version": 1}}, {"add": {"table": {"family": "inet", "name": "firewalld"}}}]}
```

Differently from the related questions that I saw, this one doesn't mention a specific rule. Any ideas?

*Note:* If I change the configuration to use iptables, then everything works. However, as iptables is being deprecated I'd like to stick with nftables

*Note:* I'm basing myself on this question: [centos 8, firewalld error `COMMAND_FAILED: 'python-nftables' failed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622426/centos-8-firewalld-error-command-failed-python-nftables-failed)